# How to get the groups that an Azure application is in

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I can get the direct groups that an Azure user is in using this [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-memberof?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#code-try-1). I want to get the direct groups that an Azure application is in. When I add an application into a group, it is displayed as a service principle. And I can see that there is an [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-list-memberof?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to get direct memberOf list for a service principle. But I do not see an API that get the group list for an application. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the **list of groups** that an application is a **`memberOf`**, you can make use of below query by including ***microsoft.graph.group***:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/<SP_objectID>/memberOf/microsoft.graph.group?$select=id,displayName,createdDateTime
```

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the below results:***

I have an **Azure AD application** named **`TestApp`** and added it to the groups like below:

[image]

Likewise, I added that application to **Group2** and **Group3** as well.

To get the **list of groups** that this application is a **`memberOf`**, I ran the below query and got results successfully as below:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/<SP_objectID>/memberOf/microsoft.graph.group?$select=id,displayName,createdDateTime
```

**Response:**

[image]

You can also use below query where you will get only **list of group IDs** that an application is a **`memberOf`** like below:

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/<SP_objectID>/getMemberGroups

{
    "securityEnabledOnly": true
}
```

**Response:**

[image]